# Can I add grout to my bathroom floor to raise the level of the grout?

Tags: bathroom, tile, grout

THis is my bathroom floor.  The grout is so much lower than the tiles.It was sealed after the floor was installed.  Dirt, dust, and everything else gets stuck along the tile when I sweep or clean.  Can I add grout to raise the level of the grout so this problem can be solved?

[image]

Comment: Not an expert, so just an opinion: You'll probably be better served by clearing the old grout out and starting fresh. Not certain how well a new layer will bond to the old layer, especially if the old layer was actually sealed at some point.

Comment: Not sure that is grout.  It looks like the tiles were pressed into the surface not levelled.  The difference in heights of the tiles would make levelling hard, if there is a product to add on top.

Comment: Or this? [Can new grout be layered on top of old grout?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/61908/35141)